# search string in html files in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am very new to iphone.In my iphone application there are about hundred html files.I would like to search a string that the user enters  in all these hundred html files and return the files that contain the string specified.
Is there any way that i could attain this in iphone?

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

Searching directly from the filesystem may be possible, but will be tremendously processor intensive. I recommend that you add the searchable contents of the files into a Sqlite database, or use a full-text search library like [Lucene](http://vafer.org/blog/20090107014544), or both.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm curious which direction you ended up going with.

Comment: I have done it, I parsed the html file with the tag names P,h1,h2 and took the text into an nsmutable string, and searched for a string using nsrange within the nsmutablestring object. if it finds then i replaced the text with yellow color using the build in API ReplaceAllOcuurencesOfString.Thank you for your valuable suggestions